# Implement piping in my own shell

Tags: c, shell, fork

I have been trying to implement piping in my own shell, but there is this bug that I am unable to fix:

For now, I am only piping two processes. I am getting the two command arguments, and passing it to `pipe_launch()`. Here is my `pipe_launch()` function:

```
int pipe_launch(char** arg1, char** arg2) {
    int fd[2], pid;

    pipe(fd);

    if( (pid = fork()) == 0 ) {
        close(1);
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        launch(arg1, STDOUT_FILENO, KHOL_FG);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid > 0){
        close(0);
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        return launch(arg2, STDOUT_FILENO, KHOL_FG);
    }
}
```

For reference, the `launch()` function:

```
int launch(char **args, int fd, int options) {

    int khol_bg = 1 ? options & KHOL_BG : 0;
    int khol_stdout = 1 ? options & KHOL_STDOUT : 0;
    int khol_stderr = 1 ? options & KHOL_STDERR : 0;
    int khol_stdin = 1 ? options & KHOL_STDIN : 0;

    pid_t pid, wpid;

    int status;

    if( (pid = fork()) == 0 ) {
        // child process

        if(fd > 2) {

            if(khol_stdout && dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, RED "khol: Error duplicating stream: %s\n" RESET, strerror(errno));
                return 1;
            }

            if(khol_stderr && dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, RED "khol: Error duplicating stream: %s\n" RESET, strerror(errno));
                return 1;
            }

            if(khol_stdin && dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, RED "khol: Error duplicating stream: %s\n" RESET, strerror(errno));
                return 1;
            }

            close(fd);
        }


        if( execvp(args[0], args) == -1 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, RED "khol: %s\n" RESET, strerror(errno));
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, RED "khol: %s\n" RESET, strerror(errno));
    } else {
        do {
            if( !khol_bg ) {
                wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
            }
            else {
                printf(YELLOW "[bg][%d] - %s\n" RESET, pid, args[0]);
            }
        } while ( !WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status) );
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Now when I run a command like `cat sorting | sort`, it executes successfully and shows the desired output, but after showing the next prompt, it exits automatically:

```
/home/sanketdg/projects/khol > cat sorting | sort
12
15
46
78
89
/home/sanketdg/projects/khol > %
```

The `%` indicates the shell has exited.

Comment: It would help if you gave a more complete example (something people can compile and run)... but anyway, what happens after `pipe_launch()` is called?  And what should it return?

Comment: Also, the conditional operator uses *<condition>* `?` *<result_if_true>* `:` *<result_if_false>* ... so, eg. `int khol_bg = 1 ? options & KHOL_BG : 0;` should probably be `int khol_bg = (options & KHOL_BG) ? 1 : 0;`, and similarly for the others.  Or just use `int khol_bg = (options & KHOL_BG != 0);` or even `int khol_bg = options & KHOL_BG;` (for the latter, only if you don't require exactly `1` for true).

Comment: And add a `break;` right after `printf(YELLOW "[bg][%d] - %s\n" RESET, pid, args[0]);` near the end of `launch()`, since in the background case `status` stays uninitialised so you can't rely on your `do...while` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is closing its own standard input, and cannot read any future commands.

```
else if (pid > 0){
    close(0);
```

(It is also performing a needless double-fork for the first part of the pipeline: one `fork()` after setting up the pipe, then another `fork()` in `launch()`.)

The `pipe()` needs to be performed in the parent shell, but I would suggest postponing the FD manipulation to the forked `launch()` child. Don't forget to close both `pipe` ends in the parent afterward.